# Sgminer No Login Credentials Supplied

Tags: mining-hardware, miner-configuration

I just started using sgminer but ran into some issues trying to get it to run correctly. Upon running my bat file I get an error saying: 'No login credentails supplied for hash-to-coins.com'. Below are my config and bat files with the worker name/password faked. If I run without the config file the miner recognizes the 9790m but will still fail to connect to the stratum. Any help is appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for several days now.

bat:
[image: bat file]

Config:

[image: config file]

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of search I finally found what was causing the issue. Apparently with Asus routers the AIProtection regarding malicious site blocking will actually block the connection to the pool. Disabling this setting in the router resolved the issue.